# Different routes for same resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, router

I have a model(resource) as job. It has its own crud operations. The View and route is different for the jobs index when seen as employee and normal user. For employee only the jobs of that particular employee should be seen while for normal users all the jobs should be seen. How should the routes and controllers be designed.

Comment: list what are the pages you need display in bullets.

Comment: You should do this in the controller... If 'user' jobs=this and that, if 'employee', jobs=such and such...

Comment: Do I get it right: employees as privileged users see less jobs than the others? And what are "normal users", should they be authenticated? This question raises more questions than useful thoughts, consider expanding the idea behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different controllers based on scope, Namespace the JobsController for the employee.

```
class Employee::JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_employee!
  layout "employee"

  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
    ....
  end
end


class UserController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end

class JobController < UserController

  def index
    @jobs = current_user.jobs
    ...
  end

end
```

Routes file

```
  resources :jobs

   namespace :employee do
    resources :jobs
    ....
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have your index controller designed to call different filters on your models based on session/cookie hash.

For example:

```
# models/job.rb
def my_jobs_only(some_variable)
    if some_variable.empty?
        Job.all
    elsif params[:my_job_area]
        Job.find(my_job_area)
    # etc...
    end
end
```

In your controller:

```
def index
    if session[:user_id]
        user = Users.find(user_id)
        job = Job.find(user)
        Job.my_filter job
    else
        Job.all
end
```

Obviously there are a lot of improvments you could make with this but that should get you going. The trick to this is that routes are best suited to just pointing to controllers and controllers are great at asking models for data.